# how to generate dummy data in mysql using stored procedure in relatable table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to generate dummy data for country and states table and the states table have a relation  with the country table using a foreign relation ship here are the tables

MYSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE country 
    (
        country_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        country_phone_code CHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        country_image VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE states
    (
       id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
       state_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       country_id INT  NOT NULL,
       FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(country_phone_code)
);
```

What i was trying was code was to create country list first and then generate for states table and save country id as a foreign key ? this is what so far i got

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateRandomData_05()
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; -- Loop counter
    DECLARE v_country_phone_code CHAR(12);
    DECLARE v_state_name VARCHAR(30);

    -- Generate random data for the country table
    WHILE i <= 150 DO
        SET v_country_phone_code := SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), 1, 12);
        INSERT INTO country (country_name, country_phone_code, country_image)
        VALUES (CONCAT('Country', LPAD(i, 3, '0')), v_country_phone_code, SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), 1, 255));
        SET i := i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    -- Reset loop counter
    SET i := 1;

    -- Generate random data for the states, city, and districts tables
    WHILE i <= 500 DO
        -- Generate random state data
        SET v_state_name := CONCAT('State', LPAD(i, 3, '0'));
        INSERT INTO states (state_name, country_id)
        SELECT v_state_name, country_phone_code
        FROM country
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1;

        SET i := i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But a lot of error comes especially with **county_phone_code not unknown error** ...

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is wrong.

You use `FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(country_phone_code)`. `country_id` is INTEGER whereas `country_phone_code` is CHAR(12). So the creation of the `states` table will fail.

After fixing this error the code works correctly: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sFq7MiVy)